# Qual o motivo de criar a pasta e não upar a imagem na sequencia?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
if ($_POST['salvar']) {
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
 // titulo duplicado
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE (titulo=:titulo)";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo);
$stmt->execute();
$noticias = $stmt->fetch();

if ($noticias)
    $erro = setError("Esse titulo da noticia ja existe !!! Altere o titulo");
else {
     $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo,conteudo) VALUES (:titulo,:conteudo)";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
    $stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo);
    $stmt->bindParam("conteudo", $conteudo);
    $stmt->execute();

    $ultimoid = DB::lastInsertId();
    $dir = "../imagens/$ultimoid";
    @mkdir("$dir", 0777);
    $uploaddir = "$dir/";

   **// a parte de upload da imagem nao funciona  ** 

    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {
    $imagem = $_FILES['foto']['name'];


   **// a parte de upload da imagem nao funciona**

    $sqlInsert = "UPDATE noticias SET imagem=:imagem WHERE idnoticia=$ultimoid";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
    $stmt->bindParam("imagem", $imagem);
    $stmt->execute();
}

if (DB::lastInsertId()) {
    setMessage("Notícia cadastrado com sucesso. ");
    redirect("noticiasListar.php");
} else {
    $erro = setError("Algum erro aconteceu");
}
```

}

so lembrando que ja pesquisei e tentei outras alternativas e nada da imagem ir para a bendita pasta

Comment: Não consigo entender a pergunta, leia por favor: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Onde está o código do upload da imagem? Só vejo o `move_uploaded` mas isso já é o final do processo. De onde veio a variável `$imagem`?

Comment: descupem eu cortei tentando fazer o que o guilherme atentou. porem tem sim o post $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];

Comment: @ArsomNolasco Cara isole o código, formule a questão, a leitura fica muito difícil do jeito que está. **Minimo legivel:** Use nomes e indentação consistentes, e se necessário inclua comentários para explicar partes do código. Praticamente todos os editores de código têm um um comando de autoformatação – encontre e use! [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ArsomNolasco Fica um pouco difícil para nós detectarmos qualquer erro quando você mesmo pode ter deixado passar vários usando o operator de supressão `@`, retire eles e veja quais erros o código apresenta. Verifique também se `$FILES['imagem']['error']` é diferente de `0`, veja [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.errors.php), coloque um `if` no `move_uploaded` também para verificar se ele não está retornando `false`.

Comment: entao Cahe tava tentando aki o seguinte : if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['error']==0)) {
            $sqlInsert = "UPDATE noticias SET imagem=:imagem WHERE idnoticia=$ultimoid";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
            $stmt->bindParam("imagem", $imagem);
            $stmt->execute();
            }else{
            $erroupload = "erro do moveupload ou update";
        } porem nao retornou nada, fez o insert no bd e criou a pasta

Comment: @ArsomNolasco faça conforme os exemplos que postei.

Answer (score 2):

Sua indentação e marcação são ruins (desculpe a sinceridade) se falhas não acontecem é por pura sorte.

Voltando ao assunto, existem os seguintes problema com o seu código:

1. `@` para omitir erros é péssimo, não omita erros quando estiver em ambiente de desenvolvimento.
2. Faça tratamento de erros com `if` e `else`
3. Feche os `IF`s no mesmo padrão, não use `if (...) echo 1;` em um lugar e outro `if (...) { ... }`
4. A indentação ajuda a **você mesmo** entender o código e evitar erros.
5. Em ambientes de produção para omitir os erros use `error_reporting(0);`
6. Existe um `{` no final de `@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {` que não tem lógica (vou presumir que foi erro de digitação na pergunta)

Como eu disse o seu código não tem *TRATAMENTO DE ERRO*, isto é simples de fazer, basta criar `else` para tudo que é possível.

Por exemplo `mkdir` e `move_uploaded_file` retornam `boolean` ou seja `TRUE` ou `FALSE`, use isto ao seu favor.

Exemplo:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);//Apenas para ambiente de desenvolvimento, em ambiente de produção comente está linha
//error_reporting(0);//Em ambiente de produção remova o comentário do inicio desta linha

...

$dir = "../imagens/$ultimoid";
if (mkdir($dir, 0777) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Erro ao criar a pasta: ', $dir, '<br>';
    exit;// é apenas um exemplo
} else {

    $uploaddir = $dir . '/';

    if(FALSE === move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {
        echo 'Ao subir o arquivo para: ', $uploaddir , $_FILES['imagem']['name'], '<br>';
        exit;// é apenas um exemplo
    } else {
        $imagem = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    }
...
```

Note que é *ALTAMENTE* recomendável que você use `rollback` do ultimo `INSERT` (se estiver usando innoDB) para evitar que existam vários registros se dados.

Se não estiver usando `innoDB` (ou qualquer outro motor compatível com `rollback`) você terá que usar `DELETE` para acaso ocorra erro durante o upload.

Exemplo de rollback (só funciona em *InnoDB* ou motores que suportem `rollback`):

> MyISAM não suporta rollback

Detalhe, dentro da sua classe você deve adicionar algo como `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);`, isto irá parar o *auto-commit*.

O código deve fica algo como:

```
$ok = FALSE;

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo,conteudo) VALUES (:titulo,:conteudo)";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
$stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo);
$stmt->bindParam("conteudo", $conteudo);
$stmt->execute();

$ultimoid = DB::lastInsertId();

$dir = "../imagens/$ultimoid";
if (mkdir($dir, 0777) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Erro ao criar a pasta: ', $dir, '<br>';
    exit;//Recomendável que você use rollback neste ponto
} else {

    $uploaddir = $dir . '/';

    if(FALSE === move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {
        echo 'Ao subir o arquivo para: ', $uploaddir , $_FILES['imagem']['name'], '<br>';
        exit;//Recomendável que você use rollback neste ponto
    } else {
        $imagem = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    }
...
//Após testar todas Ifs incluindo das queries executadas, você deve setar TRUE
$ok = TRUE;
...
//Isto deve ficar no final do código
if ($ok === TRUE) {
    $mysqli->commit();//Se TRUE então "commita" os dados no DB
} else {
    $mysqli->rollback();//Desfaz mudanças
}
```

Você também deve criar IFs para cada `$stmt->execute`